# Analysis paused due to a Calculating deferred index

Tags: resharper

Quite often I do end up with the following Resharper state:

[image]

From there, nothing in Resharper works anymore, no IntelliSense etc.

Things tried so far without success:

- pause/unpause Resharper analysis
- delete `.vs` folder

The only thing that works is restarting Visual Studio, nothing else, pretty boring.

Nothing pops up on the Internet when searching for:

> Analysis paused due to a Calculating deferred index

Any ideas ?

Comment: Do you use any ReSharper's plugins?

Comment: I do use the Unity plugin.

Comment: Are you on the latest version of ReSharper and Visual Studio? Are you able to reproduce the issue easily? I'd suggest raising a support ticket with Jetbrains.

Comment: Yes I use latest Resharper and Visual Studio versions. As on easily and deterministically reproducing it, no, but on a regular basis, yes as it does happen quite often on the scale of a week.